# GDAL does not recognize EPSG code of a shapefilefile reprojected by ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, epsg

I am using `ogr2ogr` to reproject shapefiles. For example:

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:1234 -t_srs EPSG:3857 dest.shp srs.shp
```

`ogr2ogr` then creates `dest.shp`, `dest.shx`, `dest.dbf` and `dest.prj` as expected.

The problem occurs when I try to find the EPSG code of `dest.shp` using GDAL. GDAL cannot identify that the file is in EPSG 3857.

**Why can't GDAL identify a prj's EPSG when it created the prj from a EPSG?**

Please note that I am using GDAL C# library.

Comment: Probably there is some error in how you are using GDAL/OGR. Can you show a minimal example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: AFAIK, OGR is based on GDAL. Both software packages are writing out EPSG:3857 incorrectly. "Mercator_1SP" should have both sphere- and ellipsoid-based math, so if that projection method is used, the GEOGCS portion would have to use a sphere to trigger the correct equations. Unless there's some funky workaround within the code, the results will be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if GDAL is recognizing that the projection is just EPSG:3857 by the code but I suppose that the projection info it finds is correct. Make the same test with ogrinfo. If you can't get the same info with C# then there may be something wrong in the bindings or in your code.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3857 test_3857.shp test.shp

>ogrinfo test_3857.shp -al -so
INFO: Open of `test_3857.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: test_3857
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 21
Extent: (-13557934.236980, 4655107.343957) - (-13557684.314289, 4655312.908599)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["WGS_84_Pseudo_Mercator",
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0.0]]
OBJECTID_1: Integer (9.0)
OBJECTID: Integer (9.0)
Building_U: String (50.0)
NAME_LC: String (20.0)
```