# Reprojecting with ogr2ogr -t_srs does not write AUTHORITY nodes to .prj

Tags: gdal, ogr, ogr2ogr, epsg

*(Note: This seems to be the same thing that [Mohayemin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/23408/mohayemin) ran into at  "[GDAL does not recognize EPSG code of a shapefilefile reprojected by ogr2ogr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/147047/60511)", but the comment there that "GDAL is writing out EPSG:3857 incorrectly" doesn't apply to my case here.)*

Is it me, or does `gdalsrsinfo` know and display the different EPSG codes for an SRS, but a shapefile reprojection using `ogr2ogr -t_srs <targetSRS> <dst> <srs>` does not write these EPSG codes to the shapefile's .prj file?

---

I have a shapefile `shapes.shp` that I presume to be in an EPSG:4647 projection.
`gdalsrsinfo shapes.shp` gives me

```
PROJ.4 : '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=32500000 +y_0=0
          +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["ETRS89_UTM32",
    GEOGCS["GCS_ETRF_1989",
        DATUM["ETRF_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",32500000.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

For comparison, `gdalsrsinfo EPSG:4647` shows this definition:

```
PROJ.4 : '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=32500000 +y_0=0
          +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (zE-N)",
    GEOGCS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",32500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4647"]]
```

So it's basically identical, apart from the `AUTHORITY` nodes and the `TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`, right?

But since I'd like to have these `AUTHORITY` nodes in there to make it easier to identify the projection later, I call `ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4647 shapes_4647.shp shapes.shp`. This results in <sub>(a gazillion warnings about feature fields not being convertible due to type width, which I ignore as spurious, and ...)</sub> a new shapefile called `shapes_4647.shp`, with this projection:

```
PROJ.4 : '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=32500000 +y_0=0
          +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["ETRS89_UTM_zone_32N_zE_N",
    GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",
        DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",32500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

Note: no `AUTHORITY` nodes anywhere.

I thought that including the EPSG codes in the target SRS would be trivial, given that they are obviously on file *somewhere*...

Should I just manually overwrite `shapes_4647.prj` with the "official" SRS WKT returned by `gdalsrsinfo EPSG:4647`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want, can you try this command for console

ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:32617 sample.shp newsample.shp
i'm work this. 
or 
if you need a specific area from your shp can you use this
ogr2ogr -clipdst xmin ymin xmax ymax bounding.shp mylayer.shp

have you a .tif?

if you have a .tif and you need a .shp can you use gdal_polygonize
gdal_polygonize.py sample.tif -f "ESRI Shapefile" mylayer.shp

http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html
http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html
http://www.gdal.org/pages.html

Comment: Yes, I _did_ RTFM for `ogr2ogr`, thank you.   My question would be: when you perform `ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:<whatever>` on a shapefile that a) can be converted to EPSG:<whatever>, and b) does not itself contain a valid EPSG AUTHORITY node, does your resulting .prj file contain an AUTHORITY node?

Comment: Yes, you can reproject in other EPSG using  ogr2ogre -t_srs EPSG:32616  input.shp output.shp and if not have a EPSG, also you can use              ogrinfo -ro -so  input.shp

Comment: All files in format .shp having a EPSG just reproject or overwrite

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see where your answer answers my question. Did you read it? I know how to reproject, and I know how to read the SRS info of my shape files. The question is: a) why doesn't a reprojected shape file's .prj file automatically contain the relevant EPSG codes? -- and b) what can I do (short of manually editing the .prj file myself) to add these EPSG codes to the .prj file? Are there, say, any secret `ogr2ogr` parameters to auto-add the EPSG codes during reprojection?