# EPSG code lost when writing shapefile with sf

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, gdal, r, ogr

I've found that the EPSG can be recorded in the `.prj` file of a shapefile using the `"AUTHORITY["EPSG","xxxx"]` syntax. However, writing a shapefile with `sf::st_write()` doesn't seem to add that entry, and the EPSG code is lost when re-reading that shapefile. Patching the `.prj` file manually seems to work. Minimal reprex below.

What's the best way to record the EPSG in the `.prj` file?

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.5.1, GDAL 2.2.1, proj.4 4.9.3
berne <- st_point(c(26e5, 12e5))
shp <- st_sf(name = "Berne", geom = st_sfc(list(berne), crs = 2056))
st_crs(shp)
#> Coordinate Reference System:
#>   EPSG: 2056 
#>   proj4string: "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"

st_write(shp, "berne.shp")
#> Writing layer `berne' to data source `berne.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> features:       1
#> fields:         1
#> geometry type:  Point

shp_read <- st_read("berne.shp", quiet = TRUE)
st_crs(shp_read)
#> Coordinate Reference System:
#>   No EPSG code
#>   proj4string: "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs"

prj <- readLines("berne.prj", warn = FALSE)
new_prj <- gsub("]]$", '],AUTHORITY["EPSG","2056"]]', prj)
writeLines(new_prj, "berne.prj")

shp_read <- st_read("berne.shp", quiet = TRUE)
st_crs(shp_read)
#> Coordinate Reference System:
#>   EPSG: 2056 
#>   proj4string: "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
```

Comment: Seems to be the way ogr writes data, see the similar question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222326/reprojecting-with-ogr2ogr-t-srs-does-not-write-authority-nodes-to-prj (the answer is irrelevant and needs deleting).

Comment: " QGIS is using proj strings that are bound to EPSG codes. These EPSG codes are normally missing in prj files, this may lead to wrong CRS detection by QGIS." https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55545/qpj-files-on-esri-software

Comment: See also this issue on the `sf` tracker: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/11

Answer (score -4):

Use `writeOGR()` function to write the .shp file.